# How to generate the report of amount of spaces used on the SharePoint site

Tags: reports, space-usage

We've got a user who wants a detailed break-down of the space consumed by their site for the last year or so. What they want is way beyond what the Site Collection usage section will give us. Can anyone point me in the direction of a resource which would help? Is this information actually held within Sharepoint or its databases anyway?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MOSS, Have a look at: http://spdocgen.codeplex.com/

Gives you more information than you need but definitely should do for the space.

Has also been compiled to work with 2010; available here:
http://blog.lekman.com/2010/05/automating-sharepoint-deployments.html